# How to center a form?

Tags: cognito-forms

How do you center forms on a page, please?

Centering the shortcode doesn't work, and centering the shortcode *container* only centers field labels, not form fields themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Using CSS we found not one but two different ways to help this user center the Cognito Form. Either will work is most websites, but depending on how your website is set up, one could be a better option for you than the other.

Option 1:

```
.cognito {text-align:center;}
.cognito #c-forms-form{display:inline-block;}
.cognito .c-field {text-align:left;min-width:300px;}
```

Option 2:

```
.cognito {width:800px;margin:0 auto;}
```

Comment: Our site is responsive, so Option 1 worked flawlessly -- as expected. Thanks so much, Nicholas. I would upvote, but my "rep" is too low. ;-/

Comment: Hi again. I'm unsure if the code changed with an update, or if I just hadn't mentioned this before, but for anyone using this code on their own site, in Option 1, c-forms-form is a *class*, not an ID. So the second line is: 

`.cognito .c-forms-form{display:inline-block;}`